# I am writing a Python encryption program that changes the value of the symbols with time ,any ideas how to start

Tags: python, encryption

I am writing a Python encryption program that changes the value of the symbols with time ,any ideas how to start 
eg if 25 14 14 = zoo 
Then after 2 seconds or so it should be 1 15 15 = zoo

Comment: Can you post your code? also your questions may be better answered if you follow [mcve]

Comment: You could possibly use `random.choice()`, a built in module from cmd.

Comment: @exe That would be the ultimate encryption. One that nobody can decrypt.

Comment: @Selcuk That is incorrect. You could set it to a variable, lets say encryption. You then could save the number to a list that would change every time you called the random function and it would changed the string inside of it. Then you could create another variable called decryption. It would contain the whole alphabet. This would be linked to the encryption value and the alphabet containing all characters. Then you could call the decryption to decode the input a user put in. Just a thought though... after all I am a freshman in high school

Comment: It is unclear how you would decrypt this.

Comment: @exe That was a tongue in cheek comment, but encryption is one of the most difficult things to get right (as can be seen from various attacks in the wild).

Comment: @Selcuk I am very aware that encryption is very difficult. However, I didn't want to get to deep into it and would rather relate to the question so that Marv could possibly get an answer. If I was to actually do this, I would either timestamp it or hash all the characters :)

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I am trying and the decryption part is killing me

Comment: @Josh21            So far i have this
result = ''
message = ''
choice = ''



message= input (" \n Message here")
for i in range(0, len(message)):
    result = result + chr(ord(message[i]) -x)
print(result + '\n\n')
result = ''

i am going to assign a the value of time to a variable 'x'

Comment: I just joined stack overflow , still trying to understand it . Sorry if i added the code in the wrond way